# Inequalities and multiplication

Tags: inequality

Given two inequalities the rules of multiplication are said to be (check [link](http://people.sju.edu/~pklingsb/ineq.pdf) for the source):

> 1.) If $0<a<b$ and $0<c≤d$, then $0<ac<bd$
>
> 2.) If $0<a<b$ and $c≤d<0$, then $bd<ac<0$
>
> 3.) If $0<a<b$ and $c<0<d$, then $ac<0<bd$
>
> 4.) If $a<b<0$ and $c<0<d$, then $bd<0<ac$
>
> 5.) If $a<0<b$ and $c<0<d$, then no conclusion may be drawn
>   about the relative positions of $ac$ and $bd$ on the number line

How do I prove the second and fourth rules "If $0<a<b$ and $c≤d<0$, then $bd<ac<0$" and "If $a<b<0$ and $c<0<d$, then $bd<0<ac$" ?

**My Attempts:**

**1.)**
$$
0<a<b \quad\&\quad 0<c<d\\0<ac<bc \quad\&\quad 0<bc<bd \implies 0<ac<bc<bd\implies 0<ac<bd
$$

**3.)**
$$
0<a<b \quad\&\quad c<0<d\\
0<ad<bd \quad\&\quad ac<0<ad\implies ac<0<ad<bd\implies ac<0<bd
$$
Similarly,

**2.)**
$$
0<a<b\quad\&\quad c<d<0\\
0>ac>bc \quad\&\quad bc<bd<0\implies ? 
$$

**4.)**
$$
a<b<0 \quad\&\quad c<0<d\\ad<bd<0 \quad\&\quad ac>0>ad\implies ?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *2)*, you can use *1)*:
$$d\le c < 0\quad\Rightarrow\quad 0 < -c \le -d,$$
so by 1), $0 < -ac < -bd$ and thus $bd < ac <0$.

**Edit:**  Note that item 2) as stated is false. I've left this here under the hypothesis that the conclusion of 2) is actually misstated.

For *4)*, note that $b<0$ and $d>0$, so that $bd<0$. Further, $a$, $c<0$, so that $ac>0$.

Comment: thnx. but what is given is $c<d<0$. rule 2.) seems to be wrong. What abt rule 4.)?

Comment: I misread the statement of (2). As the other answer points out, (2) is actually false. If you mistyped the conclusion, then my answer above works, possibly after substituting some variable names.

Comment: thanx. what about 4.)?

Comment: I edited the answer to include this case.

Answer (score 0):

2) is not true: take $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=-5$, $d=-2$, then the inequality is not satisfied since $2(-2) \not<1(-5)$
If you ment $ac<bd$ then you just need to observe that $|a|=a<b=|b|$ and $-|c|=c<d=-|d|$ hence $ac=-|ac|<-|bd|=bd$

Comment: thanx. rule 2.) seems to be wrong given your example. Can i confirm it is rather "If $0<a<b$ and $c<d<0$, then $ac<bd<0$". What about the 4th rule ?. Pls check the source link i have edited the post.